# Unit testing errors differing on debug and build releases

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a project, i am trying to compile it on the Win32 and Win64 compilers using Visual Studio 2010. Primarily for the focus on Win 32. With the build chain i can compile the project and generate the exe for the Project both (debug and Release). However its quite starnage behaviour. The Source contains the test cases may be around 150 or so. 
when i am executing the Release, it goes upto 30 Test cases are executed and stops with error message. However when i am executing the debug, in four test cases the execution stops.

Error message with Debug :-
"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt-d.exe."

CallStack Debug :-

```
msvcr100.dll!__crt_debugger_hook()  
    msvcr100.dll!__call_reportfault()  + 0x25 bytes 
    msvcr100.dll!_abort()  + 0x28 bytes 
    msvcr100.dll!__wassert()  + 0x5ff bytes 
>   unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt-d.exe!daddy::TOutputPin<val_cfg::CValCfgOutputBAP,daddy::TDefaultIntervention<val_cfg::CValCfgOutputBAP> >::reserve(bool f_defaultConstruct_b, const val_cfg::CValCfgOutputBAP * const f_placementChunkAddress_p)  Line 83 + 0x27 bytes  C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt-d.exe!val_cfg::CBAP::work_Rx(const val_cfg::CValCfgOutPins & f_ValCfgOutPins)  Line 56 + 0xf bytes   C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt-d.exe!val_cfg::CReceiver::work_Motor_14(const autobus::CAutobusBaseRx & f_RxMessage, const val_cfg::CValCfgOutPins & f_ValCfgOutPins)  Line 2563 C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt-d.exe!val_cfg::CReceiver::work(const val_cfg::CValCfgOutPins & f_ValCfgOutPins)  Line 67 C++
```

Error Message with Release :-
"Unhandled exception at 0x771a15de (ntdll.dll) in unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000005."

Callstack Release :-

```
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!CppUnit::TestComposite::run()  + 0x1a bytes  C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!CppUnit::TestRunner::WrappingSuite::run()  + 0x27 bytes  C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!CppUnit::TestResult::runTest()  + 0x1a bytes C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!CppUnit::TestRunner::run()  + 0x54 bytes C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!unittest_framework::testRoutine()  + 0xdc bytes  C++
    unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!_main()  + 0x8a bytes    C++
>   unittest_framework-win32-vc_100-x86-mt.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x17 bytes   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

First of all i am trying to figure out why it behaves differnetly.
Project Configuration: Win Console, Win32, Congi type:- Makefile.

Comment: You win the award for most useful title ever.

Comment: @BenVoigt I honestly prefer this to a descriptive title whose body contains "here code, i gets error :(" but no copy of the actual error message or stacktrace.

Comment: @us2012 - The original title was actually "Error message!" or thereabouts. :-)

Comment: @middaparka I know. My point still stands :P .

Comment: Thank you giving the honour for the Title... :)

I am trying to figure it out, I have to make it running on three different platforms, ARM 32bit compiler on which no issues, win32 and win64. with Windows i have issues..

Any Inputs to trace out info more..!!!